# Create random 2d array in rust

Tags: rust

How would you create a random 2d array in rust equivalent to numpy's:

```
np.random.rand(3, 2)

array([[0.81103811, 0.51529836],
       [0.02255365, 0.28580315],
       [0.97909856, 0.05897878]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ndarray-rand](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray-rand) crate which is an integration of [rand](https://crates.io/crates/rand) and [ndarray](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray) crate.

This is the equivalent code for `np.random.rand(3, 2)`

```rust
use ndarray::Array;
use ndarray_rand::{rand_distr::Standard, RandomExt};

fn main() {
    println!("{:.4}", Array::<f64, _>::random((3, 2), Standard));
    // Example Output:
    //[[0.3762, 0.5176],
    // [0.0949, 0.3432],
    // [0.8329, 0.5704]]
}
```

- `Array::<f64, _>` can be changed to different types like
  `Array::<u64, _>` to get random value from u64 set.
- `Uniform` distribution can be used to earn flexibility to have custom range
- https://crates.io/crates/rand_distr is directly exported by ndarray-rand you can have implementation of probability distributions from here: https://docs.rs/rand_distr/latest/rand_distr/#distributions, or you can implement your custom [distribution](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/distributions/trait.Distribution.html)
- RadnomExt also provides functionality like [sample_axis](https://docs.rs/ndarray-rand/0.14.0/ndarray_rand/trait.RandomExt.html#tymethod.sample_axis) to select random axis(for numpy users*; I believe this is similar to `numpy.random.Generator.choice` )

### Dependency

Since `ndarray-rand` is a Random Extension for `ndarray` crate you'll need `ndarray` crate in your project, your **Cargo.toml** should look like this:

```ini
[dependencies]
ndarray-rand = "*" #todo select compatible version to ndarray vice-versa
ndarray = "*" #todo ...
```